# jQuery Selector help

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

```
...
<tr>
    <td>222</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>333 222</td>
</tr>
...
```

And I have this code for selector:

```
$("#TableName tr td:contains('222')");
```

Problem: I need to select the cell that the html is '222' only.
I try use `$("#TableName td tr[html=222]")` but don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use `.filter()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do an exact match.

```
var result = $("#TableName tr td").filter(function() {
    return $.text([this]) === "222";
});
```

This uses `$.text()` to compare the text value of the `<td>` with `"222"`. It's just a little quicker way of doing `$(this).text()`. Gives you the same result. *(Note that you need to pass `this` in an Array `[this]`.)*

When there's a match, the element is returned into the resulting jQuery object.

If there's any possibility of leading or trailing white space in the `<td>`, you can trim that [with `$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/).

```
return $.trim( $.text([this]) ) === "222";
```

---

**EDIT:** You could create your own selector that will accomplish the same task if you want:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    textIs: function(elem, i, attr) {
        return ($.trim( $.text([elem]) ) === attr[3]);
    }
});
var result = $("#TableName tr td:textIs(222)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this implemenation of such selector (in comments in http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$.expr[":"].econtains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || $(obj).text() || "").toLowerCase() == meta[3].toLowerCase();
}
```

Example:

```
$("div:econtains('john')").css({ color: "#F00" });
```